# /usr/bin/env 'node' Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, linux, service, systemd, tileserver-gl

I installed Node V10.19.0 and tileserver-gl

I created a bash file in my home directory, by the name tileserver.sh

Which contain this code:

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1024x768x24" tilerserver-gl NewZeland.mbtiles
```

When I executed it works fine, and listening on port 8080
and I created service of this file in /etc/systemd/system/tileserver.service and enabled

```
sudo systemctl status tileserver.service
```

It shows this error:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tileserver.service: enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: Failed (Result: exit-code) since .....
process: 3729 ExecStart=/home/tilesServer/tileserver.sh ( code=exited, status=126)
Main PID: 3729 ( code=exited, status=126)
mar 26 18:21:57 tileserver systemd started tileserver bash script runing
mar 26 18:21:57 tilerserver tileserver.sh[3729] : /usr/bin/env "node' Permission denied
mar 26 18:21:57 tileserver systemd[1]: tileserver.service: main process exited , code=exited, status=126/n/a
mar 26 18:21:57 tileserver systemd[1]: tileserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

How to resolve this issue and error

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and install It as normal user, after your installed NVM you should install NodeJS with `nvm install stable` to get node stable version and then you will can test.

Comment: I should use node v10 cause , it recommended by tile server, error 126 means that command was found by not executable,

Comment: I understand friend, you could use nmv install 10 to get this node version.

Comment: And I do have NVM

Comment: if you have problem with several version installed, remove manually all and only keep NVM and although It you should install node 10.

Comment: still the issue is not solved. i only have one node version installed

Answer (score 0):

First I add the nvm path to bachrc 
start to debug it.  With root

> node debug tileserver-gl

It work fine , so I modified the script and working fine